# output : "was unexpected at this time" , what's wrong with this code?

Tags: batch-file

I saw a simple code in some book that suppose to return a list of file and folder names at the root of c:\ with a prefix of 'n - (file/folder name)' . ('n' as file\folder number of the list).

I tried to run this on cmd and on powershell 5
both output is: "my old windows shell script"
"was unexpected at this time"

EDIT**************************
the purpose is to run this as .cmd file in both cmd and in PS 
EDIT**************************

```
@echo off
echo my old windows shell script
set x=0
for /f "tokens=*" %%i in ('DIR /b C:\') do call :output "%%i"
echo script complete!
goto :EOF

:output
set name=%1
set /A X=X+1
echo %X% = %name%
goto :EOF
```

Comment: This is batch, not actually powershell code. The "batch-file" is, I think,  the correct tag

Comment: can't replicate. Runs fine in `cmd` window and `powershell` window.

Answer (score 1):

to be run in powershell this code should be saved as a batch file (.bat) and run with the command invoke-expression:

```
$command = @'
cmd.exe /C C:\work\myfile.bat
'@
Invoke-Expression $command
```

Comment: thanks but the purpose of this is to execute this as a .cmd file
it's from a PS book i'm reading

Comment: how do i run multiple line command? when i hit enter the '>>' sign keep poping...

Answer (score -1):

Your batch commands from above saved in a batch file e.g. `test.bat` are running by using `CMD`on Windows10 Pro Version 1903.

**Output:**

```
D:\>test
my old windows shell script
1 = "CacheMenu"
2 = "Intel"
3 = "PerfLogs"
4 = "Program Files"
5 = "Program Files (x86)"
6 = "Python27"
7 = "Users"
8 = "Windows"
script complete!

D:\>
```

Comment: tried this on both PS and cmd both gives the same output : 
 "my old windows shell script" "was unexpected at this time"